# Drupal 8: Form fields are not updating when checking triggering element

Tags: 8, forms

I have added a button to the node add form which allows the user to import data from the last node created into this one. Within hook_form_alter, I have:

```
// Import previous month's data if requested
$trigger = $form_state->getTriggeringElement(); //Check to see if button pressed

if ($trigger['#name'] == 'import_previous') {
  $id = \Drupal::request()->query->get('field_patient'); //grab node id from url
  $previous = st_access_patient_get_previous($id); //grab actual node
  $previous_array = $previous->toArray(); //cast node to array

  // Match up data from previous node to fields in this form, set default value
  foreach ($previous_array as $label => $field) {
    if (substr($label, 0, 5) == 'field' && $form[$label]['#access'] == TRUE) {

      if (array_key_exists('#default_value', $form[$label]['widget'])) {
        if (array_key_exists('target_id', $field[0])) {
          $form[$label]['widget']['#default_value'] =  $field[0]['target_id'];
        } else {
          $form[$label]['widget']['#default_value'] =  $field[0]['value'];
        }
      } else {
        if (array_key_exists('target_id', $field[0])) {
          $form[$label]['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $field[0]['target_id'];
        } else {
          $form[$label]['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $field[0]['value'];
        }
      }

    }
  }

}

$form['previous_import'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#name' => 'import_previous',
  '#value' => t("Import the previous month's values"),
  '#weight' => -9999,
  '#submit' => ['import_previous_submit'],
];
```

My understanding is that the button will just submit the form, I don't actually need

```
'#submit' => ['import_previous_submit']
```

When pressing 'import_previous' button the field values are not updated. If I remove the conditional (which just runs the replacement logic on every form load) then everything works fine. So, I know my logic for the replacement itself is correct. But once I wrap my replacement logic in:

```
if ($trigger['#name'] == 'import_previous') {}
```

Then the fields no longer update when the button is pressed. The conditional passes, so I know that is correct. Something else is keeping the form default values from being set. I have tried to add:

```
  $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  $form_state->setCached(FALSE);
```

after:

```
$trigger = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
```

and directly before the final closing tag of the conditional. I have also tried to add it to a submit function 'import_previous_submit'. No love with any of that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check the triggering element if you use it's own submit handler because the submit handler is only triggered by this element.

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['previous_import'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',  // changed to submit
    '#name' => 'import_previous',
    '#value' => t("Import the previous month's values"),
    '#weight' => -9999,
    '#submit' => ['import_previous_submit'],
  ];
}

function import_previous_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Example of altering / setting the field values. You have to adapt your foreach stuff.
  $user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
  $user_input['title'] = [['value' => 'test']];
  $form_state->setUserInput($user_input);

  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot that when submitting a form that 'default_value' is no longer in play, I need to be using 'value'. Have been looking at this for too long.